# How do I increase Visual Studio Code memory when using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, visual-studio-code

I am using JavaScript to write a solver for a simple game called Lyfoes (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by.ai91.lyfoes&hl=en). I'm doing this in Visual Studio Code, which appears to be a node.js application.

The game is a little like the classic Tower of Hanoi problem and I'm solving it by recursively calling a function. I do not know yet how to use a tree structure.

My code works well for cases of moderate complexity. However, for big problems the code fails part way through. After trying to run another node app I realized that Visual Studio Code had run out of memory (An install command line message for the other app let me know, and once I closed my solver the other application worked without this complaint).

How can I extend the memory of Visual Studio Code so that I can solve more complex problems?